# Test Proxy to see if it requires Authentication

Tags: c#, proxy, http-status-codes, http-status-code-407

I have a list of proxies that I want to loop through and test to make sure they are working and also test to make sure that they do not require a username and password.

However, the test does not seem to be working correctly.  For example I have one proxy that I know requires a username and password to use, but it is somehow getting through the test.

Here is the sample code that I have:

```
HttpWebRequest webReq = (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
webReq.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxy);
HttpWebResponse webRes = (HttpWebResponse)webReq.GetResponse();
if (webRes.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.ProxyAuthenticationRequired)
{

    Stream myStream = webRes.GetResponseStream();
    if (myStream != null)
    {
        success = true;
    }
}
```

For example the following proxy requires authentication: "66.60.148.11:3128".  However when I run the code, the webRes.StatusCode comes back as OK and passes the webRes.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.ProxyAuthenticationRequired test.

Any ideas or sugestions are appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine the request to the proxy that is allowing it through (so to speak) is not following HTTP standards by not returning a 407 status code. You can view this by doing a packet sniff with something like WireShark http://www.wireshark.org/ or using browser debug tools like Chromes Developer Tools (Ctrl+Shift+I). You could also check to see what status code is being returned by looking at the value of `webRes.StatusCode` for this case.